# Which is correct? All week Vs. a week

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Craig has been staying with his brother ___

- for all week
- for a week
- since a week

The correct answer is 'for a week'; why can’t ‘for all week’  be an answer? Is it because of present perfect continuous tense? Or due to differences between all week and a week?

Answer (score 1):

You could say "has been staying with his brother for a week" or "has been staying with his brother all week"

The structure "for [length of time]" expects a phrase like "three days" or "five minutes". So  "for all week" doesn't work.  Whereas "since" expect a phrase like "Wednesday" or "the 25th of March" or "2pm". So again "since a week" doesn't work.

Comment: So you mean ‘all week’ isn’t expression for length of time, then is it range of time? Or what?? Could you explain as well?

Comment: What James meant is that _all week_ cannot be used with _for_. _All week_ has the implied meaning of _for the whole of the past week_.

Comment: Thanks, I truly understood :)